# Extensions of continuous bounded functions

Tags: functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

If $u:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded and continuous can $u$ always be extended such that $u \in C(\bar{U})$? and is $u$ uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not always possible, let $n = 1$ and $U = (0,1) \subseteq \mathbb R$, define $u(x) = \sin(x^{-1})$. Then $u$ is bounded (by 1) and continuous, but is neither uniformly continuos nor extendable to $[0,1] = \bar U$.

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that this extension is always possible if $u$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Yes. In general we have for metric spaces $X$, $Y$, with $Y$ complete, and $A \subseteq X$ that any uniformly continuous $f \colon A \to Y$ can be extended uniquely to a uniformly continuous $F \colon \bar A \to Y$.